# dc.js: How to crossfilter complex object?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a complex JSON object and want to crossfilter the data (keys should be x-axis and values y-axis), how can I do it with this Object?

```
signalData: {
    signal1: {
      name: "",
      data: {2,3,1,4,5,1,3},
    },
    signal2: {
      name: "",
      data: {2,3,1,4,5,1,3},
    },
    signal3: {
      name: "",
      data: {2,3,1,4,5,1,3},
    },
```

I think the main think is to crossfilter the data key, because I want to work with this data in 3 different charts.

Here a graphic that maybe describes better what i want to do ;)

[image]

And here is some code:

```
var data = {
   "1": 10,
   "2": 20,
   "3": 30,
   "4": 40,
   "5": 50,
   "6": 60
 };
var dataModel = Object.keys(data).map(function(d) {
  return {
     key: +d,
     value: data[d]
   };
});
signalCF = crossfilter(dataModel);
signalDim = signalCF.dimension(dc.pluck("key"));
signalGroup = signalDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  return d.value; });
```

Comment: Crossfilter can only filter on the main array which you pass to the constructor. You can set up a ["tag dimension"](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays) so that each row is filed under multiple keys, or you can flatten the data so that there is one array with multiple columns (say signal1, signal2, signal3). But you haven't said what you want to do with the data, so it's hard to say what is the right approach for your situation.

Comment: signal1, signal2 and signal3 will be different charts. Each different chart should be filled with its own data key. I want to filter the data of all these 3 charts with a fourth range filter chart. Maybe you can help me a bit more now? Maybe i have to model my dataset in another "shape" or something like that?

Comment: Yes, you probably have to reshape / flatten the data, since crossfilter only takes an array. I guess you are talking about range/focus charts but other than that I can't figure out what you are trying to do, sorry. It takes some practice to learn how to ask good, self-contained and descriptive questions on SO! I would recommend using the edit feature to add more detail to your question, since stuff just gets buried in the comments.

Comment: So i can pass a multi-dimensional array into the crossfilter? If yes how do i address the different datasets in the dimension and group?

Comment: Not really. Crossfilter will only filter on the main array dimension, so if you want to filter by signal*, you could change your data into an array and then use accessors. But if you want to filter in the data dimension, you will need to flatten your data so that the data key is at the main array level. I'm not clear what the key would be - data looks like it is just observations with no key. Maybe it would be better to take this broad conversation to [the users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/dc-js-user-group)? Comments are a lousy medium for trying to explain.

Comment: I added a picture that shows what i want to do.

Comment: What is the key (X axis)? Just the integer index? Like I said, flatten your data into a single array with a field per signal. It’s not clear to me if you are doing any filtering (range/focus is just zooming really) but if you are, you will need all your data in one flat array.

Comment: My x axis is the Object key and the y axis the object value.
Yes i filter the data i do it like this:

`var data = {
  "1": 10,
  "2": 20,
  "3": 30,
  "4": 40,
  "5": 50,
  "6": 60
};

var dataModel = Object.keys(data).map(function(d) {
  return {
    key: +d,
    value: data[d]
  };
})

signalCF = crossfilter(dataModel)

signalDim = signalCF.dimension(dc.pluck("key"))
signalGroup = signalDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});
`
But i dont know how to work with multiple datasets for multiple charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if we are using the same definition of "filter"; I meant to ask if you are planning to use the filtering feature of crossfilter, that is brushing in one dimension and seeing only the selected data **in an unrelated view**.

The range/focus feature does not require filtering because all charts are on the same dimension and no data gets filtered.

Assuming you do want to filter on this data dimension, you need to flatten your data.

If your original data looks like

```
signalData: {
    signal1: {
      name: "",
      data: {2,3,1,4,5,1,3},
    },
    signal2: {
      name: "",
      data: {2,3,1,4,5,1,3},
    },
    signal3: {
      name: "",
      data: {2,3,1,4,5,1,3},
    },
```

Your flattened data might look like

```
[
  {
    signal1: 2,
    signal2: 2,
    signal3: 2
  },
  {
    signal1: 3,
    signal2: 3,
    signal3: 3
  },
  {
    signal1: 1,
    signal2: 1,
    signal3: 1
  },
  {
    signal1: 4,
    signal2: 4,
    signal3: 4
  },
  // ...
```

This is the only point I am trying to get across, the rest of this should be obvious...

I would be wary of using `Object.keys` on an array. It probably works, but data might get out of order. `d3.range` will do the same thing.

Adding the key to the above data:

```
var dataModel = d3.range(0, data.length).map(function(d) {
  return {
     key: +d,
     ...data[d]
   };
});
```

Now the data will look like

```
[
  {
    key: 0,
    signal1: 2,
    signal2: 2,
    signal3: 2
  },
  // ...
```

And you could define dimensions and groups like:

```
signalCF = crossfilter(dataModel);
signalDim = signalCF.dimension(dc.pluck("key"));
signalGroup1 = signalDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  return d.signal1; });
signalGroup2 = signalDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  return d.signal2; });
```

Obviously, you could also write code to flatten your data structure into this kind of data. The only point I am trying to get across is that crossfilter's native format is a flattened array; it's possible to squeeze data of other formats, but filtering will only work if the data is an array.

Here is some code to do the transformation. Rotating column-major data to row-major data is a common task and I usually use [d3.range](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/v2.8.0/README.md#range) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this, although there are other ways.

```
function rotate_data(odata) {
  const keys = Object.keys(odata),
    len = d3.max(keys, key => odata[key].data.length); // 1
  if(keys.some(key => odata[key].data.length < len))
    console.warn('warning: data not same length; padding with zeros'); // 2
  return d3.range(0, len).map(i => keys.reduce(
    (p, k) => (p[k] = odata[k].data[i] || 0, p), {key: i}); // 3
}
```

`rotate_data` calculates the maximum-length `data` field of all the values of the object (1). Then it issues a warning if any of these arrays are not that length (2). Finally (3) it maps the integers [1, length) to a new array of objects with

- a field `key` of the integer `i`
- a field for each of the keys of the original object, containing the `i`th value of the corresponding array

I tested the function [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/8kzmrfqd/7/). Note that there was a typo in your example data - the array should be enclosed in square brackets not curly.

Comment: Hmm i dont realy know if you understood wich data i want in x and y-achsis. In y-achsis i want the data in the object (data: {2,3,1,4,5,1,3}) in the x axis i just want the indexes where the values are in the data object ({0,1,2,3,4,5,6})

Comment: Yep, this should do that.

Comment: Thank you! How could a function to flatten the data look like?

Comment: Okay, I added an example of code to rotate the data above.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i have a bit more complex problem which is a bit beyond the scope of stack overflow i think. Is there a way to get in toch with you?

Comment: Sorry, I only like to answer questions on SO and [the user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!forum/dc-js-user-group) because I can reach a lot more people that way. It’s likely someone else has the same question or will be helped by the conversation!